# How can I change the Web server that the NetBeans profiler uses?

Tags: netbeans, webserver, profiler

NetBeans 8.2 profiler uses the web-server that comes with the IDE: Tomcat 8.0.27.0. I added the Tomcat of another version that interests me to IDE, but i did not find a way to switch to it. If i remove the old server from the IDE, the profiler still tries to work by default. How can I switch the profiler to another web-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't associate the server to be used with the Profiler; you associate the server to be used with the web application you want to profile. To do that:

Step 1 of 3: Create the server:

- Create the server that you want to use (i.e. Tomcat, Glassfish, Payara etc.) in NetBeans.
- Verify that you can **Start** and **Stop** it from under the **Servers** entry in the **Services** panel.

Step 2 of 3: Associate your web project with that server:

- Select your web project in the **Projects** panel.
- Right click and select **Properties**.
- Select **Run** from the list of **Categories**.
- Select the server you want to use from the **Server** drop list. In this case I chose to use Glassfish 4.1.1:

[image: ChooseServer]

Step 3 of 3: Profile your web application:

- Select your web project in the **Projects** panel.
- Right click and select **Profile**.
- Click the **Profile** button. Immediately you will see that the server you just selected for running your web application (Glassfish 4.1.1 in my case) is being used.

[image: ProfileUsingServer]

This is a [good nine minute introductory video on using the Profiler](https://youtu.be/DI4EFkzqCCg) on NetBeans 8.1+ which may be helpful.